# Scroll through two gridviews at a time

Tags: android, gridview, scroll

I want to scroll through two grid views at once. Currently, if i set the outside layout with the grid layout, it will go out of the screen, so I inevitably set it as a linear layout. Please give me a solution ..

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"

    >
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/week_dayGridView4"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:numColumns="1">
</GridView>

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/week_dayGridView3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/purple_200"
    android:numColumns="7"
    android:padding="1dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="1dp"
    >
</GridView>
</LinearLayout>
```

here is the [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLpny.png)